# Enable CORS on multiple images at once

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, cors

I know we can use this code to enable CORS on a single image

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = '';
img.src = 'http://crossdomain.com/image.jpg';

canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

Is there any way to do it for multiple image URLs at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## URL array

To load several images enabling CORS request, you can use an array which is practical for this purpose.

One thing to be aware of is that requesting CORS can be denied by server. The browser may fail loading the image in those cases so you will need to know in advance if CORS need to be requested or not.

### Example loader

```
var urls = [url1, url2, url3, ...];   // etc. replace with actual URLs
var images = [];                      // store the loaded images
var i = 0, len = urls.length;
var count = len;                      // for load and error handlers

for(; i < len; i++) {
     var img = new Image();
     img.onload = loadHandler;
     img.onerror = img.onabort = errorHandler;
     img.crossOrigin = "";            // enable CORS request
     img.src = urls[i];               // set src last
     images.push(img);                // store in array
}

function loadHandler() {
    if (!--count) callback();         // loading done
}

function errorHandler() {
   // handle errors here
   loadHandler();                     // make sure to update counter/callback
}

function callback() {
    // ... ready, continue from here
}
```

## Demo

```js
var urls = [
      "http://i.imgur.com/0LINzxs.jpg",   // random urls from imgur..
      "http://i.imgur.com/6ksiMgS.jpg", 
      "http://i.imgur.com/aGQSLi9.jpg"
    ];
    var images = [];                      // store the loaded images
    var i = 0, len = urls.length;
    var count = len;                      // for load and error handlers
    
    for(; i < len; i++) {
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = loadHandler;
         img.onerror = img.onabort = errorHandler;
         img.crossOrigin = "";            // enable CORS request
         img.src = urls[i];               // set src last
         images.push(img);                // store in array
    }

    function loadHandler() {
        if (!--count) callback();         // loading done
    }

    function errorHandler() {
       // handle errors here
       loadHandler();                     // make sure to update
    }

    function callback() {
        // ... ready, continue from here
        console.log(images);
        var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0);
        ctx.drawImage(images[1], 0, 0);
        ctx.drawImage(images[2], 0, 0);
        console.log(ctx.canvas.toDataURL());  // OK if CORS is OK!
    }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score -2):

### Put the srcs in an array and iterate over them

working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ps50po4z/
This allows you to use multiple images from different sources and display them.
use this function as a template to iterate through all the cors src images

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var sources = {
        darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
      };

      loadImages(sources, function(images) {
        context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 100, 30, 200, 137);
        context.drawImage(images.yoda, 350, 55, 93, 104);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: CORS is Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) ... So, what we have here are 2 images with origins that are not from the site jsfiddle. How is this not what the OP is asking for?

Comment: CORS usage must be requested by setting img.crossOrigin  before src. Also, the onload handler should be shared. You can *draw* images from any source, but CORS triggers when you want to extract pixels (toDataURL/getImageData)

Comment: I see. Good description. Never the less, doesn't this code preform as a proposed solution to the OP's problem? He can add images from multiple sources and display them. Correct me if I am wrong, again.

Comment: This code, as-is, does not solve the problem no (IMO). I would suggest editing it so that the CORS request problem, which is what OP is after, is included in it.

Comment: No? images loaded from other domain than the origin? Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: That is not the point, if the cross-origin images are drawn into canvas they will taint it preventing reading anything from canvas. The problem is not loading and drawing them (as stated above)

Comment: why is the error message "undefined is not a function". Doesn't seem to be related to CORS? right?

Comment: ops, I was gonna use getImageData, changed heart. Doesn't change the point though. Here is a new version, and yes, it seem to be very much related to CORS: https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/nbfnw4zf/ Let me know if you still don't understand the problem. :)