# Javascript images loading function hangs up my browser

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, while-loop

I'm trying to make simple game in Javascript and HTML so I need images function to load sprites. I'd like it to wait until image is loaded and then proceed to another image. Unfortunatly code I wrote stops my browser from working. I think that it's endless while loop that should be finished.

Here's my code:

```
var Sprites = {};
function NewSprite( Name, URL )
{
    Sprites[ Name ] = new Image( );
    Sprites[ Name ].Ready = false;
    Sprites[ Name ].onload = function ( )
    {
        this.Ready = true;
    }
    Sprites[ Name ].src = URL;

    while ( Sprites[ Name ].Ready === false );
}
```

When I run it without while loop at the end and check `Sprites[ Name ].Ready` value it gives me `true` so I think it should work.

I'm calling my function like this:

```
NewSprite( "img", "http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-100-100-6.jpg" );
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded meaning it can only execute one part of the code at any time.

This line:

```
while ( Sprites[ Name ].Ready === false );
```

will block the browser from doing anything else, including setting `Ready` state, which means the loop will continue forever and eventually triggering script blocking in the browser. Events are *asynchronous*, but must not be confused with multi-threaded (which is a different thing).

You need a different approach to solve this

```
var Sprites = {};
function NewSprite( Name, URL, callback ) {
    Sprites[ Name ] = new Image( );
    Sprites[ Name ].Ready = false;
    Sprites[ Name ].onload = function ( ) {
        this.Ready = true;
        // continue from here
        callback(this);       // use a callback
    }
    Sprites[ Name ].src = URL;

    //while ( Sprites[ Name ].Ready === false );  Will block browser...!
}
```

Now you can use the code this way:

```
NewSprite("img", url, function(image) {
    // continue from here...
});
```

Though, this has been answered many times here on SO. Here is **[one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629219/enable-cors-on-multiple-images-at-once/29630168#29630168)** on how to load multiple images and continue when done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll need to study your answer for a while, because I'm Javascript newbie. Could you quickly explain me what `callback(this);` does?

Comment: @Jacajack callback is the function you pass in. callback(this) will trigger that function and pass in `this` which in this context (onload handler) is the actual image.